# Better rewrite of code in an update query

Tags: mysql, sql, join, sql-update

```
UPDATE media_title u1,
(SELECT
u1.`id`, CONCAT(u1.`local_title`,'-',ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY u1.`local_title` ORDER BY u1.`id`) + 1) newname
FROM 
media_title u1 JOIN (SELECT `local_title` , COUNT(*) FROM media_title GROUP BY `name` HAVING COUNT(*) > 1) u2
ON u1.`local_title` = u2.`local_title` ) u3
SET u1.`local_title` = u3.`newname`
WHERE u1.`id` = u3.`id`
```

What I wan't to accomplish with the code above is to update previously added titles in the table media_title after the user adds another title by the click of a button. I don't wan't to update the table in question after the users have added movies to their catalogs but when they do that in real time. I hope this will clearify what I wan't. Thank you all for your attention!

```
-----------------------------
ID | Local title
-----------------------------
1  | Title A
-----------------------------
2  | Title A-2
-----------------------------
3  | Title A-3
-----------------------------
4  | Title A-4
-----------------------------
5  | Title B
-----------------------------
6  | Title C 
-----------------------------
7  | Title C-2
-----------------------------

Thank you so much for your attention and my best wishes!

Kind regards,
Ingmar.
```

Answer (score 2):

There's definitely a bit of a smell about this but, is this what you are looking for?

```
UPDATE media_title mt1
JOIN (
    SELECT id, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY local_title ORDER BY id) rn
    FROM media_title
) mt2
    ON mt1.id = mt2.id AND mt2.rn > 1
SET mt1.local_title = CONCAT(mt1.local_title, '-', mt2.rn);
```

If you are trying to run this, add more duplicate titles, and then run again, it won't work as the titles have already been modified. Have a look at this very simple example:

| id | title |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | title |
| 2 | title |
| 3 | title |

Running the above query (or your original one) will update it to:

| id | title |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | title |
| 2 | title-2 |
| 3 | title-3 |

You then add another `title` to your db:

| id | title |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | title |
| 2 | title-2 |
| 3 | title-3 |
| 4 | title |

The only two titles which are going to be grouped in the same partition are 1 & 4, so when you run the query again you end up with:

| id | title |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | title |
| 2 | title-2 |
| 3 | title-3 |
| 4 | title-2 |

You could modify the query with something like this, which removes the `-{###}` from the title so that all titles can be grouped again:

```
UPDATE media_title mt1
JOIN (
    SELECT
        id,
        IF (local_title REGEXP '\-[0-9]+$', LEFT(local_title, REGEXP_INSTR(local_title, '\-[0-9]+$') - 1), local_title) lt,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY IF (local_title REGEXP '\-[0-9]+$', LEFT(local_title, REGEXP_INSTR(local_title, '\-[0-9]+$') - 1), local_title) ORDER BY id ASC) rn
    FROM media_title
) mt2
    ON mt1.id = mt2.id AND mt2.rn > 1
SET mt1.local_title = CONCAT(mt2.lt, '-', mt2.rn);
```

but this is even more insane than the previously suggested query. If you have a large movie DB (9.4M+ titles in my IMDb test database), this type of query is going to be very slow. If running immediately after adding `new_title`, adding `WHERE local_title LIKE 'new_title%'` to the inner query will improve performance dramatically when combined with a prefix index on `local_title`.

A better approach would be to check for the duplicates before adding a new title and increment the suffix before inserting the new title.

Comment: Thank you very much for your kind reply! Im sorry to say that it is not working as intended. It can only update two rows after the second row the output becomes the same as the previous one. I am struggling very hard with this.

Comment: I am working on a very large movie database and I wan't to support duplicated titles by adding an incrementing number after them, thats the first thing I am trying to do. I succeed with the code I got so far in this post but only until the incrementing number reaches title-1, title-2 after a form submit action it won't increment beyond title-2. Why is that? Is there another way to do this without using partition. Its so awkward. Could this be done on the php side maybe? I dont want break context or anything like that. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I have modified my question in this post now. Hopefully things will become more clear.

Comment: I believe I got it up to working now thanks to your supplied code. Thank you so much @nnichols. It was the regex part that did the job I think. This was great!

Comment: Please remember to accept an answer if it resolves your question. If using this approach, remember my suggestion about adding the `WHERE` clause to the subquery.